# PyMongo AND condition when system argument is null

Tags: mongodb, find, pymongo

I am using PHP to pass system arguments to PyMongo to fetch data.  I have multiple system arguments.  For example:

**PHP**

```
$Vdat = ["Company1", "Company2"];
$Market = ['Market1','Market2'];
$pyexecdb = "/usr/bin/python3 getdata.py " . base64_encode(json_encode($Vdat)) . " " .  base64_encode(json_encode($Market));
```

**PyMongo**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import urllib.parse
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import json,sys
import base64



username = urllib.parse.quote_plus('uid')
password = urllib.parse.quote_plus('pwd')
client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@ipaddress:27017' % (username, password))
db = client['db']
col = db['collection']

Vdata = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
vdat = eval(Vdata)
Market = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[2]))
market = eval(Market)

ndf = col.find({ "$and": [ { "VendorName": {"$in": vdat } },{ "City": {"$in": market} } ]})
```

**Sample Data**

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5eff011c7cbc297f7122d9cc"),
   "SrlNo": "72808",
   "VendorCode": "V000246",
   "VendorName": “Company1",
   "City": “Market1”
},
{
"_id": ObjectId("5eff011c7cbc297f7122d9cb"),
   "SrlNo": "72809",
   "VendorCode": "V000247",
   "VendorName": “Company2",
   "City": “Market2"
}
```

This works well when both `vdat` and `market` values are available.  However, in many instances I would be having only vdat or market.  Is there a way where I can run the above `col.find` with `and` condition, even when one of the sys.argv is null.  I have many sys.argv's hence the possibility of writing multiple if conditions is ruled out.

I understand we could use `$ifnull` and `$unwind` parameters in mongodb but not sure how to use them in this scenario.

**Expected output**

Expected output is to run the following query even if one of the variables `vdat` or `market` is null

**example**

```
ndf = col.find({ "$and": [ { "VendorName": {"$in": vdat } },{ "City": {"$in": market} } ]})
```

Comment: Can you add your sample doc and expected output?

Comment: @Gibbs added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by making your input a single JSON arg.  This will avoid potential whitespace issues on the command line and gives you more flexibility in the future for additional args.

```
python3 '{"vdat":["company1","company2"], "mkt":["market1","market2"]}'
```

Next, since you want to keep your command line args separated from the actual field names in the query but keeping it dynamic, use a mapper as follows:

```
    arg_items = json.loads(argv[1])

    argmap = {
        "vdat":"VendorName",
        "mkt":"City"
        }

    andlist = []
    for k, v in argmap.items():
        if k in arg_items:
            andlist.append({v: {"$in": arg_items[k]}})

    if len(andlist) > 0:  # make sure we picked up at least 1 thing from command line:
        ndf = col.find({ "$and": andlist })
```

Comment: Many thanks...your solution helped me in resolving many issues.